# Как заставить элемент прокручиваться выбирая наименьший путь?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css3, html5

Как сделать так чтобы при добавлении класса объект не прокручивался через всю ось а искал наименьший путь.
Т.е. в примере, чтобы он не прокручивался назад, а прокручивался вперёд т.к. это наименьший путь

https://jsfiddle.net/snrm8701/4/

360 градусов это максимум допустимое значение.

Надо чтобы встал на позицию 17, но не прокручивался назад, а вперёд. Как то сделать чтобы прокрутился до 360 т. а потом от 0 до 17. Главное чтобы "наименьшим путём"

```js
$('body').click(function() {
 $('div').toggleClass('r');
});
```

```css
div {
  background: #000;
  height: 50px;
  width: 10px;
  color: white;
  transition: 1s all;
  transform: rotate(343deg);
}

.r {
  transform: rotate(17deg);
}
0
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>1</div>
```

Comment: ну так положительный градус - по часовой, отрицательный - против .... `transform: rotate(377deg);`

Comment: @MedvedevDev 360 максимум

Answer (score 1):

Костыль конечно, но типа, раз такие условности ...

```js
$('body').click(function() {
 $('div').toggleClass('r');
});
```

```css
div {
  background: #000;
  height: 50px;
  width: 10px;
  color: white;
  transition: 1s all;
  transform: rotate(343deg);
}

.r {
  animation: mymove .2s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes mymove {
  50% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
  50.001% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { transform: rotate(17deg); }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>1</div>
```

Comment: Да, я тоже ничего лучше не придумал https://jsfiddle.net/snrm8701/81/

Comment: @АртёмPeGaS, так 377 градусов же .... на чистом css я не представляю как это ещё можно решить, а вот на js найти кратчайший путь до нужного угла (но с неограниченным углом) - это запросто ..